# Toast behavior on API Level 28?

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I noticed while testing my apps that Toast behavior is different in API 28

The following code displays nothing on Android 9, while on older devices it shows the message

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"TEST",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
toast.show();
```

Is it possible to overcome this and actually display the toast when multiple events occur in a short period of time?

Comment: You might find [my `Toast` wrapper useful](https://gist.github.com/mobiRic/9786993) - it cancels existing toast when a new one needs to be displayed.

Comment: It's perfect, @Richard. It behaves the same on all API versions I've tested. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped - I've been using it a long time across many production apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a countdowntimer, this works till 100 msec in my test. Below 100 msec toast doesn't show up. If you need faster, need to subclass Toast IMHO.

```
public static void showToast(Context context, String message, int duration) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    new CountDownTimer(duration, duration) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            toast.cancel();
        }
    }.start();

    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sinan, but this does not answer my question. You can definitely NOT use 100 for 100 msec. The third parameter is either Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG

Comment: @AlexBusuioc you're right. Have a look at my edited answer. Hope this helps.